# Is it advisable to store UNIQUEIDENTIFIER data in VARCHAR type?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

In a table, I do have a column of type `VARCHAR(50)`. I am storing some alpha-numeric dat` in the same. The data are of different length i.e. inserted from user input.

Now, I do have a requirement to store `NEWID() - UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` type of data in the same. But I have already existing data that I can not modify. So, instead of converting the datatype of column from `VARCHAR` to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` I am thinking about storing `NEWID()` in the `VARCHAR` format in the same column.

Is it advisable to do the same?

Comment: use nvarchar instead of varchar

Comment: The bigger question is: why does that column have multiple uses/meanings?

Comment: I agree with @MitchWheat: if that column has **two meanings** - it really should be **two separate columns** (think about the **Single Responsibility Principle!**) - one `varchar(50)` for what you already have, and another, new `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column for storing the GUIDs

Comment: I can not make two saperate columns for this because to do so I need to change lots of code at server application and several stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If the column you are speaking of is not to be used as a primary key or index, then you will not have any issues - you can store there whatever you want.
- If the column has already been an index or even primary key, you will have the same issues you already have (regarding to your post saying the data is of variable length)
- If you introduce an index or primary key when making this change, then you should take into accounts the possible performance impacts of using a variable length column for this.

  - A good advice, if the above is innevitable, would be to attempt to reduce the size of the column to 36 (I think this was the standard length of the unique identifiers generated by most systems and frameworks, including the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type of SQL Server, which is represented via 5 alpha-numerical entities, totally constituting of 32 symbols separated with (4) hyphens).
  - If your current data can be sized to 36 symbols safely, I recommend redefining the column **before** making it an index or PK, especially if your table has many rows already.
  - If possible, also redefine it as CHAR(36) (or even NCHAR(36) as advised in comments) - fixed length columns perform better as indices. Also, MS SQL server 2005 and above support the [`NEWSEQUENTIALID()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) function for generating sequential ids. These perform better for index or PK columns.